# How do you handle ProgressPercentage not returning 100?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

I am using the node @aws-sdk/client-timestream-query 3.53.0 package. I am running into an issue where the result of ProgressPercentage is not 100 but the promise returned.

```
    const promise = this.client
      .send(command)
      .then((data) => parse(data))
      .catch((err) => err);

    this.cache.set('accountPlatforms', promise);
    return (await this.cache.get('accountPlatforms')) || []
```

Then inconsistently we will get results that return like this from the promise.

```
{
    "$metadata": {
        "attempts": 1,
        "httpStatusCode": 200,
        "requestId": "redacted",
        "totalRetryDelay": 0
    },
    "ColumnInfo": [
        {
            "Name": "platform",
            "Type": [
                null
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "success",
            "Type": [
                null
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "failure",
            "Type": [
                null
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "total",
            "Type": [
                null
            ]
        }
    ],
    "NextToken": "redacted",
    "QueryId": "redacted",
    "QueryStatus": {
        "CumulativeBytesMetered": 10000000,
        "CumulativeBytesScanned": 108896,
        "ProgressPercentage": 67.63129689174706
    },
    "Rows": [
    ]
}
```

I don't see a way to look up the completed query either by requestId or queryId from inside the our service.

Anyone know how to get the completed query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the "NextToken" from the first query result you obtain and use it to make a new query using it, if the ProgressPercentage<100.
You will then have the result.

This is the way i do.

Like in Python i do:

```
if query['QueryStatus']['ProgressPercentage']<100:
        next_token = query['NextToken']
        query = timestream_query_client.query(QueryString=queryString, NextToken=next_token)
```

Hope it helps also after time or who is coming next having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

a progress percentage < 100 means that the query is not yet done. This is returned from Amazon Timestream in case the query runs longer than the defined timeout. Whenever you see this, you should expect that rows[] is empty but you get a NextToken.

You can poll with next token as described here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/code-samples.run-query.html